# Check if data is found in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I was a making request for firebase to find the Score of current user. That works fine, however I need to check also does it have any score. If so the score is getting displayed on Toast message. If score does not exist show 0.
I tried to use child.exist() method but it seems not working as it only shows the score if its found. But shows no response for !child.exist() method.

Maybe somebody could tell me what I am doing wrong ? Thanks[image]

```
DatabaseReference leadersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Leaders");
    Query query = leadersRef.orderByChild("uID").equalTo(mCurrentUser.getUid());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                if(child.exists()){
                    currentScore = child.child("Score").getValue(Integer.class);
                    Toast.makeText(RunningChallengeActivity.this,"Your current score: " + currentScore,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if(!child.exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(RunningChallengeActivity.this,"Your current score: 0 ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query that doesn't match any children will return a snapshot without any children. So you'll need to move the check for results *outside* of the for loop in your code:

```
DatabaseReference leadersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Leaders");
Query query = leadersRef.orderByChild("uID").equalTo(mCurrentUser.getUid());
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                currentScore = child.child("Score").getValue(Integer.class);
                Toast.makeText(RunningChallengeActivity.this,"Your current score: " + currentScore,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(RunningChallengeActivity.this,"Your current score: 0 ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```